# How to get the result of a future within the builder method of a FutureBuilder widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have looked all over and cannot seem to find a solution to this problem. I have a `Future<bool> = isAuth`.

I have a future builder defined as follows:

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: isAuth,
  builder(context, snapshot){
    if(connectionState == connectionState.done){
      // Some Code Here
    }

    if(connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
      CircularProgressIndicator()
    }
  }
```

My question is, how do I return one widget if `isAuth` returns `true`, and another if `isAuth` returns `false`? I am displaying a loading spinner while waiting on the result of `isAuth`, and once I have the result, I want to display one of two forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a `FutureBuilder`'s `future` value with `snapshot.data`.

Don't forget to check if `snapshot.data` is defined using `snapshot.hasData` :

```dart
FutureBuilder<bool>(
  future: isAuth,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if(connectionState == connectionState.done){
      if (snapshot.hasData){
        if (snapshot.data) return TrueWidget();
        else return FalseWidget();
        // Or with a one-liner :
        // return snapshot.data ? TrueWidget() : FalseWidget();
      }
    }

    if(connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
      return CircularProgressIndicator(); // Don't forget to return a widget in a builder method
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
new FutureBuilder<bool>(
        future: isAuth, // async work getting the call for true of false
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
    bool value = snapshot.data;
           switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
             case ConnectionState.waiting: return new Text('Loading....');
             default:
               if (snapshot.hasError)
                  return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
               else
              return value ? 
new Text('sample one'): Text('sample two')
            }
         },
        )
```